# What are the requirements to graduate?

Tags: discussion, support

I have seen that this is the next step and that we have to take at least 180 more days to do it with no time limit. What even are the requirements though? I saw the "Leaving Private Beta, and Initial Pro-Tempore Moderator Election!" but it doesn't say the hard requirements. What are they?

Comment: So we can graduate now!? @Seggan-OnStrike

Comment: Nvm I misread the question. Still, IIRC there are no *hard* requirements

Comment: It's in the Area 51 [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Area 51's FAQ:

> At any point after being in public beta for 6 months, if the site has at least 1000 open questions, 70% of which have at least one upvoted answer, the Community Team will coordinate with the community to start the process of removing the site’s beta label.

So thats the requirements I guess. However, this doesn't seem to be completely true. I found [Substrate and Polkadot](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/) SE which has met all of these, but I see nothing about removing the beta label. Also, then whats the Area51 stats for?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers.